# @elastic/elasticsearch error when building a docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, elasticsearch, npm

I'm getting an error when trying to run the docker image of a nodejs project. I've tried building with different versions of elasticsearch (7.14.1 and 7.4.0) and I keep getting the same error. When I run locally (using `npm install` and `npm start`) I don't get any errors.

Steps to replicate are as follows:
`docker build . -t <project-name>:<version>` <--this command works fine

`docker run <image-name>:<image-tag>` <--this returns the error below

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:carbon

RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt-get install -y curl

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

# RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8082
CMD [ "node", "./src/server" ]
```

Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Helpers.js:75
  async * scrollSearch (params, options = {}) {
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/index.js:28:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/connectors/elasticSearchConnector.js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
```

I am using node 12.22.1. Has anyone else encountered this error and if so how did you resolve it?

Edit: Adding the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "<repo name>",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "./src/server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.22.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./src/server --ignore client",
    "rollback": "knex migrate:rollback",
    "migrate": "knex migrate:latest && knex seed:run",
    "resetDB": "knex migrate:rollback && knex migrate:latest && knex seed:run",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .  --ext .js",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --fix .  --ext .js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^7.4.0",
    "acorn": "^8.4.1",
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bull": "^3.11.0",
    "bunyan": "^1.8.15",
    "bunyan-postgres-stream": "^1.5.2",
    "config": "^1.30.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "csv-writer": "^1.5.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "downloads-folder": "^1.0.1",
    "elasticsearch-scroll-stream": "^1.2.1",
    "exceljs": "^1.9.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-redis-cache": "^1.1.3",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "geoip-lite": "^1.3.7",
    "helmet": "^3.15.1",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "json2csv": "^4.5.4",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^0.95.10",
    "knex-migrate": "^1.7.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.21",
    "node": "^12.22.1",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "objection": "^1.2.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "permission": "^1.1.0",
    "pg": "^8.0.3",
    "redis": "^2.8.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "tempfile": "^2.0.0",
    "tz-lookup": "^6.1.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "husky": "^1.0.0-rc.8",
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7"
  },
  "repository": "<repo>",
  "license": "<license>"
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the package.json?

Comment: Yep! Added package.json to the question